# Inter-operability of Swift arrays with C?

Tags: objective-c, c, swift

How can one pass or copy the data in a C array, such as

```
float foo[1024];
```

, between C and Swift functions that use fixed size arrays, such as declared by

```
let foo = Float[](count: 1024, repeatedValue: 0.0)
```

?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think this is easily possible. In the same way as you can't use C style arrays for  parameters working with a `NSArray`.

All C arrays in Swift are represented by an `UnsafePointer`, e.g. `UnsafePointer<Float>`. Swift doesn't really know that the data are an array. If you want to convert them into a Swift array, you will have create a new object and copy the items there one by one.

```
let array: Array<Float> = [10.0, 50.0, 40.0]

// I am not sure if alloc(array.count) or alloc(array.count * sizeof(Float))
var cArray: UnsafePointer<Float> = UnsafePointer<Float>.alloc(array.count)
cArray.initializeFrom(array)

cArray.dealloc(array.count)
```

**Edit**

Just found a better solution, this could actually avoid copying.

```
let array: Array<Float> = [10.0, 50.0, 40.0]

// .withUnsafePointerToElements in Swift 2.x
array.withUnsafeBufferPointer() { (cArray: UnsafePointer<Float>) -> () in
    // do something with the C array
}
```

Comment: Surely the array with unsafe pointer must copy the contents, as it doesn't know how long it will stay allocated?

Comment: @jhabbott That's why it's "unsafe" :). Depending on the internal representation of Array<> it may have to perform a copy to a contiguous memory area if it doesn't already exist in one, but this is probably reasonably unlikely/infrequent in practice.

Comment: Looks like ```withUnsafePointerToElements``` was removed: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10_3/modules/Swift.html

Comment: U saved my life

Answer (score 12):

As of Beta 5, one can just use pass &array
The following example passes 2 float arrays to a vDSP C function:

```
let logLen = 10
let len = Int(pow(2.0, Double(logLen)))
let setup : COpaquePointer = vDSP_create_fftsetup(vDSP_Length(logLen), FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2))

var myRealArray = [Float](count: len, repeatedValue: 0.0)
var myImagArray = [Float](count: len, repeatedValue: 0.0)
var cplxData = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &myRealArray, imagp: &myImagArray)

vDSP_fft_zip(setup, &cplxData, 1, vDSP_Length(logLen),FFTDirection(kFFTDirection_Forward))
```

Comment: How about an example that doesn't show real world code? It's not very clear which parts are what you're trying to demonstrate and which are just part of the C API you're using.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert DSPSplitComplex is a part of the Apple Accelerate framework which is a C API and is a good example. It is a simple struct for holding a vector of complex numbers.

Comment: As of Swift 3, Array init is now: `var myRealArray = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: len)`

Answer (score 11):

The `withUnsafePointerToElements()` method was removed, now you can use the `withUnsafeBufferPointer()` instead, and use the `baseAddress` method in the block to achieve the point

```
let array: Array<Float> = [10.0, 50.0, 40.0]
array.withUnsafeBufferPointer { (cArray: UnsafePointer<Float>) -> () in
    cArray.baseAddress
}
```