# Where is MapKit Step polyline?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am trying to print coordinates of all route steps, similar to Google Maps SDK's "legs".

But it tells me that I cannot use `polyline` property to obtain a coordinate?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for step in self.route!.steps as [MKRouteStep] {
```

otherwise it treats `step` as `AnyObject` (which doesn't have a `polyline` property defined so you get that compiler error).

---

By the way, note that `polyline.coordinate` just gives the average center of the polyline or one endpoint.  A polyline can have more than one line segment.

If you need to get *all* the line segments and coordinates along the polyline, see [latitude and longitude points from MKPolyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861403/latitude-and-longitude-points-from-mkpolyline) (Objective-C).

Here's one possible translation to Swift (with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100764/467105)):

```
for step in route!.steps as [MKRouteStep] {
    let pointCount = step.polyline.pointCount

    var cArray = UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>.alloc(pointCount)

    step.polyline.getCoordinates(cArray, range: NSMakeRange(0, pointCount))

    for var c=0; c < pointCount; c++ {
        let coord = cArray[c]
        println("step coordinate[\(c)] = \(coord.latitude),\(coord.longitude)")
    }

    cArray.dealloc(pointCount)
}
```

As the first linked  answer warns, you may get hundreds or thousands of coordinates per step depending on the route.

Comment: Swift is confusing. I can't seem to understand the need for optionals `?` and `!` and telling compiler to treat an object `as` some other type. Why can't a Swift be simple to use like JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to get coordinates from each step of the route.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.1, as of July 2018, based on the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647603/7311767).

```
let pointCount = step.polyline.pointCount
let cArray = UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>.allocate(capacity: pointCount)
step.polyline.getCoordinates(cArray, range: NSMakeRange(0, pointCount))

for c in 0..<pointCount {
    let coord = cArray[c]
    print("step coordinate[\(c)] = \(coord.latitude),\(coord.longitude)")
}

cArray.deallocate()
```